# Pandas - Fill Column Values based on conditions on Two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to fill the values of column 3 based on condition on column 1 and 2 without having to import numpy and use np.where

DataFrame:

```
1  CNT T
2  T   T
3  T   NT
4  CNT INT
```

Condition:
if value in Column1 != 'T' and value in Column2 == 'T' then value in Column3 = value in Column1 (='CNT')
else value in Column3 == value in Column2

Output:

```
1  CNT  T   CNT
2  T    T   T
3  T    NT  NT
4  CNT  INT INT
```

What I have tried is:

```
Dataframe[3] = Dataframe.loc[(Dataframe[1] != 'T') & (Dataframe[2] == 'T'), 1]
```

but that creates
Output:

```
1  CNT  T   CNT
2  T    T   NaN
3  T    NT  NaN
4  CNT  INT NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried `np.where()` ?

Comment: You are close, need `Dataframe[3] = np.where((Dataframe[1] != 'T') & (Dataframe[2] == 'T'), Dataframe[1], Dataframe[2])`

Comment: Or `df.loc[df[1].ne('T') & df[2].eq('T'), 3] = df[1]`

Comment: apologies if this is a duplicate, @yatu that returns the same as mine.
samkart and jezrael: is there a way without having to import numpy?

Comment: @bloo - use `Dataframe[3] = pd.np.where((Dataframe[1] != 'T') & (Dataframe[2] == 'T'), Dataframe[1], Dataframe[2])`

Comment: awesome! didn't know that could be done! thanks!